# How to count numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I think my only problem is the displayCounts method. I'm trying to have the array of counts to display the count only if the count > 0. Same goes for count > 1. So the input would be like: 2 5 6 5 4 3 4 0. (0 would be what ends the input) The output would come out as: 
    - 2 occurs 1 time
    - 3 occurs 1 time
    - 4 occurs 2 times
    - 5 occurs 2 times
    - 6 occurs 1 time.

```
public class CountNumbersInArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");

    int[] counts = new int[101];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < counts.length) {
      counts[i] = input.nextInt();
      i++;
    }
    displayCounts(counts);
  }

  public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
    int i = 0;
    i++;
    if (counts.length > 0) {
      System.out.println(counts[i] + " occurs " + i + " time");
    } 
    if (counts.length > 1) {
      System.out.println(counts[i] + " occurs " + i + " times");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it like this: increment the int of the array at the position of the input, that way you can count how often one number was input, and then call an output method, which prints a line, if the value at the index i is larger than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, replace

```
while (i < counts.length) {
  counts[i] = input.nextInt();
  i++;
}
```

with

```
i = input.nextInt();
while(i != 0){
  counts[i]++;
  i = input.nextInt();
}
```

That method increments the number at the position of the user input in the counts array, that way the array holds the number of times a number occurs in a specific index, e.g. counts[3] holds how often 3 occurs.
The i != 0 in the while loop breaks the loop as soon as 0 is input and goes to the displayCounts method in the next line.

Based on that we now create a new displayCounts method:

```
public static void displayCounts(int[] counts){
  for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
    if(counts[i] > 0){
      System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counts[i] + " times");
    }
  }
}
```

That method now prints how often a number occurs if its count is greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Why not import this class?

public class CountNumbersInArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D+");
    System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");

    int[] counts = new int[101]; // So the last index is 100

    for(int i=0; i < counts.length; i++){
      int number = input.nextInt();
      if(number == 0) break;
      if(number >= 1 && number <= 100) counts[number]++;
      else System.out.println("Your number is outside the boundaries");
    }

    displayCounts(counts);
  }

  public static void displayCounts(int[] counts){
    for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) System.out.println("Number "+i+" occurs "+ counts[i]+ (counts[i] != 1 ? "times" : "time"));
  }
}
```

This code should work, what I did was:
1.

```
for(int i=0; i < counts.length; i++){
  int number = input.nextInt();
  if(number >= 1 && number <= 100) counts[number]++;
  else System.out.println("Your number is outside the boundaries");
}
```

This code gets the number user entered, and increments it's count by one. Note that this only works, because default value for Integer is 0
2.

```
  public static void displayCounts(int[] counts){
    for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) 
     System.out.println("Number "+i+" occurs "+ counts[i]+ (counts[i] > 1 ? "times" : "time"));
  }
```

This code is just better written. What was partially wrong with your code is that you had 2 if statements, instead of 1 if, and 1 else if. This way when the count was greater than 1 you had 2 "responses"

Comment: That will ask for 101 numbers from the user. It will not stop when user enters `0`, as described in question (*"0 would be what ends the input"*). And although you improved it by checking number range, it'll still crash if user enters a non-integer value.

Comment: Ok, just edited so it doesn't crush when user inputs string.

Comment: Ohhh, I like that use of delimiter: Ignore everything other than digits. Haven't seen that one before. You get a +1 for that one. --- For better result, you might want to add a `if (counts[i] > 0)` inside `displayCounts` loop, e.g. if user enters `1 1 2 0` it shouldn't print `3 occurs 0 times, 4 occurs 0 times, ..., 100 occurs 0 times`.

Comment: Well, depends on preference. Dunno what the op wants

Comment: True, but printing 98 "negative" lines when user enters two values, doesn't seem very user-friendly, does it? To me, it's just common sense to not print so much output that the relevant part(s) scrolls off the screen, and/or drowns in the flood of output.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 while (i < counts.length) {
  counts[i] = input.nextInt();
  i++;
}
```

with

```
 int in = input.nextInt();
 while (in != 0) {
   if(in > 0 && in <101){
    counts[in]++;
   } else {
     System.out.println("Please enter values between 1-100. Enter 0 to 
  stop");
  }
 in = input.nextInt();
}
```

And then iterate over you entire counts array to obtain individual frequencies of elements between 0 and 100

Comment: How would ignoring the user-entered value be a fix for anything?

Comment: My bad..check now

Comment: Ok, down-vote removed, but this in only fixing one of many problems with the code.

Comment: That will still ask for 101 numbers from the user. It will not stop when user enters `0`, as described in question (*"0 would be what ends the input"*). And although you improved it by checking number range, it'll still crash if user enters a non-integer value.

Comment: @Andreas You are right..I should have paid more attention to the question..Edited my response for future generations

Comment: Would be more readable if you indented the code correctly. Would be better to reverse check to `if (in == 0)` so you 1) check the user-entered value, and 2) don't need an `else`. And why is it stopping after user enters 101 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");

    int[] counts = new int[101];
    Arrays.fill(counts, 0);

    int i = 0;
    int inputValue;
    while (i < counts.length) {
        inputValue = input.nextInt();
        counts[inputValue]++;
        i++;
    }
    displayCounts(counts);
}

public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] > 0) {
            if (counts[i] == 1) {
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counts[i] + " time");
            }else {
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counts[i] + " times");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use else if in displayCounts method?

Comment: Yes, it is more efficient to use else

Comment: It isn't about efficiency, your code would output 2 results for one i

Comment: Check it now, it might be okay

Comment: There are so many things with this code: Array.fill(counts,0) is unnecessary(default value of a integer is 0) and the if (counts[i] > 0) doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: That will ask for 101 numbers from the user. It will not stop when user enters `0`, as described in question (*"0 would be what ends the input"*).

Comment: @Berrigan The `if (counts[i] > 0)` does make sense, because it shouldn't print `42 occurs 0 times` if user didn't enter any `42` values. I would probably move it down to change `else` to `else if`, but that's a very minor improvement, and doesn't change logic.